# Getting warning and error at same time in tornado proxy

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, tornado

It seems like i am hitting some race condition in between the time I stop my server and during that I make request through tornado proxy frontend.

I get very famous error

```
WARNING:tornado.access:404 POST /request-url/eff74/36eb5e9f-def1-4689-ad58-3bf866798864/client-update (::1) 0.88ms
ERROR:tornado.general:Cannot send error response after headers written
WARNING:tornado.access:404 POST /request-url/eff74/36eb5e9f-def1-4689-ad58-3bf866798864/client-update (::1) 1.36ms
ERROR:tornado.general:Cannot send error response after headers written
WARNING:tornado.access:404 POST /request-url/eff74/36eb5e9f-def1-4689-
```

which is described in source code [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.send_error)

Can I resolve this problem?

Point of confusion is I am getting 404 already, then why I am getting an error after wards.

Cheers

Comment: can you provide mwe?  Tornado version, is there any auth?

Comment: @kwarunek Thanks, what's mwe? Tornado version: Version: 4.2.1, no auth.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example that we can reproduce it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was very silly bug in my code.
Bug was the proxy function which was handling "requests" wasn't issuing "return" statement from the function.

Example:

```
def proxy_handler(self, request, response):
    # some task
    response.set_status(status_code)
    response.send("status_code: message")
    return # this was missing earlier
```

So tornado was trying to send respons which already has been sent. Thus getting the error

```
WARNING:tornado.access:404 POST /request-url/eff74/36eb5e9f-def1-4689-ad58-3bf866798864/client-update (::1) 1.36ms
ERROR:tornado.general:Cannot send error response after headers written
```

Cheers